# React setState() callback issue, cant access to output variable

Tags: reactjs, dom, event-handling, target, setstate

In the code below I could not access console.log(event) inside the callback of setState().

```
handleChange(event){
    let a = event
    console.log(event)
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value,
    },()=>{
        console.log(event)
        // console.log("test",this.state)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aeeylv)

```
 handleChange(e) {
            let name = e.target.name;
            let value = e.target.value;
            this.setState({ name: value })
          }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the event to the callback that's why you are not able to access it. Change your code like this:

```
handleChange(event){
    let a = event
    console.log(event)
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value,
    },(event)=>{
        console.log(event);
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({name: e.target.value}, ()=> {
  console.log(this.state.name)
})
```

*Hope this solves the problem.*